# Not able to compare response body parameter to its value

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, rest-assured

My Response Json is below which i want to compare its value

```
{
    "Result": {
        "user": {
           "PersonData": null,
            "Locale": null,
            "Attributes": {
                "IsEnabled": null,
                "LocaleSettings": null,
                "LockoutEnabled": "True",
                "AccessFailedCount": "0"
            }
        },
        "RefreshToken": "745acf0f-de47-4f4c-8abe-b3d7d505fc60",
        "Success": true,
        "Errors": null
    },
    "StatusCode": "200",
}
```

Here is my code where i have written some assertions

```
given().body(request.toJSONString()).header("Content-Type", sitedata.getProperty("Content-Type"))
                .header("ApplicationCode", sitedata.getProperty("ApplicationCode"))
                .header("Authorization", sitedata.getProperty("Authorization")).when()
                .post(sitedata.getProperty("BaseUrl") + sitedata.getProperty("login"))
                                .then().log().all().statusCode(200)
                .body(Matchers.containsString("Success"))
                               ** .body("Result.Success", Matchers.equalTo("true"));**
```

I am getting below error

```
JSON path Result.Success doesn't match.
Expected: true
  Actual: true
```

I want to validate its value should be true

Comment: Just remove the quotes from Matchers.equalTo(true) and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong match. You are trying to compare **boolean** `true` vs **text** `"true"`

So since their string representations are equal the matching error message looks misleading.

You should change the last line of your code to `.body("Result.Success", Matchers.equalTo(true));`